# bolding target word in Anki

Tags: javascript, anki

Sentence: Wir gehen ins Kino um 19 Uhr.

Word: Kino

I have this script to make the word kino bolded:

```html
<div id="word" hidden>{{Word}}</div>

<script>
  (() => {
const word = document.getElementById("word").innerText;
const sentenceEl = document.getElementById("sentence");
    sentenceEl.innerHTML = sentenceEl.innerHTML.replace(
      // case-insensitive regular expression
      new RegExp(word, "gi"), `<b><i><span style=' '>${word}</span></b></i>`
    );
  })();
</script>
```

but if Word: das Kino · Kinos · Kinos

the word kino doesn't get bolded in the sentence, so i want to edit the code

I know nothing about programming.

Comment: it only works with kino, the same as old code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think that the code `const word = document.getElementById("word").innerText;` is wrong. We must use `let word = document.getElementById("word").textContent;`

Secondly, the replace regex should be simple as this

```
let sentence = document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML;
  const regex = new RegExp(word, "gi");
  sentence = sentence.replace(regex, `<b><i>${word}</i></b>`);
  document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = sentence;
```

Remember to close the html tag with right position.

See the demo here https://codepen.io/giang-vincent/pen/eYPgKep?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Test unique changes

```html
        <div id="word" hidden>Word</div>
        <div id="sentence">Hello Word word woRd wOrD World</div>
    <div id="sentence2"></div>

        <script>
          (() => {
        const word = document.getElementById("word").innerText;
    const sentenceEl = document.getElementById("sentence");
    const sentenceEl2 = document.getElementById("sentence2");

    sentenceEl2.innerHTML = sentenceEl.innerHTML.replace(
              // case-insensitive regular expression
              new RegExp(word, "g"), `<b><span style=' '>${word}</span></b>`
            );
        
            sentenceEl.innerHTML = sentenceEl.innerHTML.replace(
              // case-insensitive regular expression
              new RegExp(word, "gi"), `<b><span style=' '>${word}</span></b>`
            );
        

          })();
        </script>
```